# Applet to run native code from browser. Almost works but is throwing exception

Tags: java, exception, browser, applet

Wrote an applet to open native code in a browser. It works when I run it from my IDE as a file, but when I run it from my browser using glassfish as a local host to serve it up the code throws an exception.

```
package rootapplet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;

public class RootApplet extends javax.swing.JApplet{
    int number;
    private File file;

    public void init(){

    //test code
        number = 42;
    }

    public void start(){
        new Exception().printStackTrace();
        try{
            File f = new File("C:\\Windows\\System32");
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","start","Notepad.exe");
            pb.directory(f);
            Process process = pb.start();
            //ProcessBuilder derp = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe","myfile.txt");
            //derp.start();
            System.out.println("Words words words");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Stuff didn't work");
        }
    }
    public void paint (Graphics screen){
        Graphics screen2D = (Graphics2D) screen;
        screen2D.drawString("The square root of "+number+" is "+Math.sqrt(number),5,50);
    }
}
```

I left the other ProcessBuilder method, not in the coding sense, in the code because both ProcessBuilders work. But I get the same issue with each when I run it from my localhost. I am assuming that it is an IO exception and I am just not passing the correct file path to the the applet. If that is the case, does anyone know what I should pass it instead of what I am? And if not, what might be happening?

Stack Trace

```
java.lang.Exception
          at rootapplet.RootApplet.start(RootApplet.java:18)
Words Words Words
          at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:475)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Java Console output

```
security: Certificate validation succeeded using OCSP/CRL
security: Saving certificates in Deployment session certificate store
security: Saved certificates in Deployment session certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
network: Created version ID: 1.0+
network: Created version ID: 1.0
security: Expected Main URL: http://localhost:8080/classes/rootapplet/RootApplet.class
network: Cache entry found [url: http://localhost:8080/classes/rootapplet/RootApplet.class, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://localhost:8080/classes/rootapplet/RootApplet.class
cache: Resource http://localhost:8080/classes/rootapplet/RootApplet.class has expired.
network: Connecting http://localhost:8080/classes/rootapplet/RootApplet.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8080/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: ResponseCode for http://localhost:8080/classes/rootapplet/RootApplet.class : 304
network: Encoding for http://localhost:8080/classes/rootapplet/RootApplet.class : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://localhost:8080/classes/rootapplet/RootApplet.class
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8080/classes/, version: null]
security: Grant socket perm for http://localhost:8080/classes/ : java.security.Permissions@452267 (
("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost" "connect,accept,resolve")
)

network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.60
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.65
0
basic: Embedding dialogs not enabled in Configuration
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.60
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.65
security: SSV validation:
    running: 1.7.0_55
    requested: 1.7.0_55
    range: null
    javaVersionParam: 1.7.0_55
    Rule Set version: null
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.55
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.55
security: continue with running version
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.55
network: Created version ID: 1.7
network: Created version ID: 2.2.55
security:  --- parseCommandLine converted :
into:
[]
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 930624 us, pluginInit dt 6880938 us, TotalTime: 7811562 us
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
Stuff didn't work again
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
network: Checking for update at: https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/blacklist
network: Checking for update at: https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/baseline.version
network: Checking for update at: https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/blacklisted.certs
network: Connecting https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/blacklist with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/baseline.version with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/blacklisted.certs with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jre7/lib/ext/sunec.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jre7/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
security: Loading Root CA certificates from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts
security: Loaded Root CA certificates from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts
security: Loading SSL Root CA certificates from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts
security: Loaded SSL Root CA certificates from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer ROOT certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer ROOT certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
network: Updating file at: C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\baseline.versions from url: https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/baseline.version
network: Updating file at: C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\blacklisted.certs from url: https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/blacklisted.certs
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.60
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.65
network: Updating file at: C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\blacklist.dynamic from url: https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/blacklist
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.60
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.65
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own solution. I had to wrap it up as a jar and run it using the archive tag within my applet tag in the HTML I was calling it from.

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace you are seeing is not generated by a thrown Exception but by the one you construct in the first line of start():

```
new Exception().printStackTrace();
```

The output "Words Words Words" intermingled with that stacktrace is only visible because **no** Exception was thrown and the last line of the try block was executed.

In your console output there is a line "Stuff didn't work again" which is not generated by your source.

For debugging purposes it might be helpful to expand your catch-block:

```
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Stuff didn't work");
    e.printStackTrace
}
```

And maybe remove the irritating line "new Exception().printStackTrace();"

Comment: You are absolutely correct. No exception is thrown when I run the applet from my IDE, which is the only manner in which I have tested my stack trace. I will take your suggestion and send it up the server to see what it does there.

Comment: @Unihedron added the info, though I suspect copy+paste+corrections to be at fault here, since the class won't compile with "Private" (as well as with the unclosed string literal "Word words words)

Comment: Well the thing compiles on the PC where I wrote the thing to begin with. Is there something about the way I pass the location of the program that might be causing an issue?

Comment: do you get a stack trace when running in glassfish with the change I proposed?